# Python script to download PDF not downloading the PDF?

Tags: python, pdf, urllib, urllib3

I have a Python 3.10 script to download a PDF from a URL, I get no errors but when I run the code the PDF does not download. I've done a sanity check to ensure the PDF is actually on the URL (which it is)

I'm not sure if this maybe has something to do with HTTP/ HTTPS? This site does have an expired HTTPS certificate, but it is a government site and this is really for testing only so I am not worried about that and can ignore the error

```
from fileinput import filename
import os
import os.path
from datetime import datetime
import urllib.request
import requests

import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings()

resp = requests.get('http:// url domain .org', verify=False)
urllib.request.urlopen('http:// my url .pdf')

filename = datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d-%I_%M_%S_%p")
save_path = "C:/Users/bob/Desktop/folder"
```

Or maybe is the issue something to do with urllib3 ignoring the error and urllib downloading the file?

Redacted the specific URL here

Comment: I don't get it: your script doesn't have any code that actually saves the downloaded file...

Answer (score 1):

The [`urllib.request.urlopen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen) method doesn't save the remote URL to a file -- it returns a response object that can be treated as a file-like object. You could do something like:

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen('http:// my url .pdf')
with open('filename.pdf') as fd:
  fd.write(response.read())
```

The [`urllib.request.urlretrieve`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve) method, on the other hand, will take care of writing the remote content to a local file. You would use it like this to write the PDF file to a local file named `filename.pdf`:

```
response = urllib.request.urlretrieve('http://my url .pdf',
                                      filename='filename.pdf')
```

See the documentation for information about the return value from the `urlretrieve` method.

Comment: I think I see what you're saying and I think I got it now, but I am now running into an issue trying to name the file with the current date and time stamp. I keep getting an error, ```OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%D-%I_%M_%S_%p")' ```

Comment: If you you just use a static string as the name, does it work? If so, I think you have an answer to your original question, and you may want to open a new question about your issues with `datetime` and `strftime`.